# Как правильно задать положение для картинки и текста. Подробности в описании

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```css
.position img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content-right {}

.content-left {}
```

```html
<div class="about">

  <img class="position" src="img/about1.jpg" alt="О нас">
  <p class="content-left">
    July 2010 Our Humble Beginnings
  </p>


  <img class="position" src="img/about2.jpg" alt="О нас">
  <p class="content-right">
    January 2011 Facing Startup Battles
  </p>


  <img class="position" src="img/about3.jpg" alt="О нас">
  <p class="content-left">
    December 2012 Enter The Dark Days
  </p>


  <img class="position" src="img/about4.jpg" alt="О нас">
  <p class="content-right">
    february 2014 Our Triumph
  </p>

</div>
```

Хочу сделать так чтобы напротив картинки был текст с лева и справа.

1.Текст слева - Статичная картинка по центру
2.Статичная картинка по центру - Текст справа
3.Текст слева - Статичная картинка по центру
4.Статичная картинка по центру - Текст справа

[image: Примерно так должно это выглядеть]

Скриншот из PSD

Comment: А что именно не получается?

Comment: Залейте код полностью.

Comment: нажми править под вопросом и потом значок `< >`, далее все интуитивно....

Comment: Обновил, добавил код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно как бабуля Ванга - только догадываюсь 
*пример смотреть на полном экране*

```css
*,h3,p{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.item{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.items{
  margin:0 20px;
}
h3{
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
img{
  border-radius:50%;
}
.parent{
  width:70%;
  margin:auto;
}

.a{
  transform:translate(110px,0);
}

.b{
  transform:translate(-110px,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="item a">
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <h3>placehold.it</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item b">
  <div class="items">
    <h3>placehold.it</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item a">
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <h3>placehold.it</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="item b">
  <div class="items">
    <h3>placehold.it</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь меня как раз интересовало размещение текста по центу относительно картинки.

Comment: у меня в лендах это очень часто заказывают .. и потому заготовка была готовая ... потому и вывалил результат быстро ...